# My task is to to update spark dataframe which has column of type string and struct. I am trying to do in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

```
Id         Identifers
'123'      {"country":"PR", "idType":"SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}
'234'      {"country":"PR", "idType":"NOT SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}
```

Need to change the `$Identifers.status = "Done"` when `idType` is equal to `"SELECTED"`

So Expected **`OutPut`** will be

```
Id         Identifers
'123'      {"country":"PR", "idType":"SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}
'234'      {"country":"PR", "idType":"NOT SELECTED","status":"Done"}
```

I tried using

```
df.withColumn("$NewIdentifers", when($"Identifers.idType" === "SELECTED", "DONE"))
```

But this failing giving Null

Answer (score 0):

Starting from **Spark-2.2**:

You can use **`from_json`**(to create individual cols) and **`to_json`**(recreate json object) in built functions for this case.

**`Example:`**

```
//sample data
df.show(false)
//+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
//|Id |Identifiers                                                  |
//+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+
//|123|{"country":"PR", "idType":"SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}    |
//|234|{"country":"PR", "idType":"NOT SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}|
//+---+-------------------------------------------------------------+

import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

//defining the schema
val sch=new StructType().add("country",StringType).add("idType",StringType).add("status",StringType)

//read the identifiers using from_json and pass the schema
val df1=df.withColumn("jsn",from_json(col("Identifiers"),sch)).select("Id","jsn.*")

//required json cols
val jsn_cols=df1.columns.filter(_.toLowerCase != "id")

//here we are using when otherwise and updating status column then recreating json object using to_json function

df1.withColumn("status",when(col("idType") === "SELECTED",lit("Done")).otherwise(col("status"))).
withColumn("identifiers",to_json(struct(jsn_cols.head,jsn_cols.tail:_*))).
drop(jsn_cols:_*).
show(false)

//+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
//|Id |identifiers                                                 |
//+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
//|123|{"country":"PR","idType":"SELECTED","status":"Done"}        |
//|234|{"country":"PR","idType":"NOT SELECTED","status":"Not Done"}|
//+---+------------------------------------------------------------+
```